# Error abrir una web en Iphone "Ocurrió un problema varias veces en https://www..."

Tags: url, chrome, iphone, safari

Por si les pasó a alguien...
tengo un sitio de noticias y al abrir cualquiera de las paginas aleatoriamente me sale y **solo en IPHONE** (safari ó chrome) un mensaje de error : "Ocurrió un problema varias veces en (url pagina)"; al darle recargar la web ya se muestra correctamente.
Tengo otros sitios idénticos en configuración y no tengo ese problema.
Revise el .htaccess y se ve todo igual a los otros sitios.
Pasa lo mismo eliminando caché de los navegadores, etc.

Gracias!